# Can Madame Vastra use her tongue like some other Silurians?

Tags: doctor-who

The Silurians in *Cold Blood* and *The Hungry Earth* used their tongues as weapons, of sorts, and caused a man to begin to mutate.  Vastra seems to appear similar to them, however, she doesn't seem to show any inclination towards that sort of fighting.  Instead, she usually uses a sword.

**Is there any evidence proving that Vastra can use her tongue as a weapon, and if so, why doesn't she?**

Comment: A tongue is personal and maybe she isn't wanting to go around licking every person she has to fight. In the instances I have seen her use it, it was because it was expedient, nothing more. I think she wants to NOT appear too different from her Human lover.

Comment: Jenny is a lucky girl

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, in her very first appearance in "A Good Man Goes to War", Madame Vastra uses her tongue to disable an enemy soldier:

Transcript:

> **Vastra:** Was I being insensitive again, dear? I don't know why you put up with me.
>
> (She turns and lashes Lucas with her extendible tongue.)
>
> <sup><sub>[*Doctor Who* Series 6 Episode 7: "A Good Man Goes to War"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/32-7.htm)</sub></sup>

As to why she doesn't use her tongue more often, we don't have an in-universe explanation<sup>1</sup>. One reasonable possibility is that it becomes very obvious that she doesn't fit in; in "Deep Breath", we learn that this is rather important to her:

> **Vastra:** I wear a veil as [The Doctor] wore a face for the same reason.
>
> **Clara:** What reason?
>
> **Vastra:** The oldest reason there is for anything. To be accepted.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Doctor Who* Series 8 Episode 1: "Deep Breath"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/34-1.html)</sub></sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Out-of-universe, Moffat probably doesn't want to waste budget on the CGI when the sword serves perfectly well

Comment: Actually I answered first, but he addressed both questions, and I only got the first one, so he deserves the point :)

Comment: IIRC, the venom shot could only be used once every so often as the venom sac needed replenishing. Alaya only used it once(?)  in Hungry Earth/Cold Blood - you'd expect her to use it more if she could.

Answer (score 6):

Yes - she does so around 20:57 of [S06E07 A Good Man Goes to War](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2curm8_doctor-who-s06e07-a-good-man-goes-to-war_tv).  She and Jenny are in a control room of Demon's Run when a tied-up baddie tries to reach the alarm.

[image]